# How to detect an async operation is successful or not in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

In my app, after authentication, user can move to the next screen.

```
              signUpWithEmail().then((user) {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return HomePage();
                }));
              }).catchError((error) {
                print("THE ERROR : $error");
              });
```

Now `signUpWithEmail` may fail for various reasons like : invalid e-mail, internet connectivity failure and so on. How can I detect those errors and prevent navigation? Here is signUpWithEmail() method:

```
  Future<FirebaseUser> signUpWithEmail() async {
    String email = emailControlller.text;
    String password = passwordControlller.text;

    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailControlller.text,
      password: passwordControlller.text,
    )
        .then((user) {
      // set balance to 0
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .document(user.uid)
          .setData({"cash": 0});
    }).catchError((e) => print("error : $e"));

    return user;
  }
```

Comment: The `.catchError` exists for that you need.

Comment: @Augusto Updated my code with catchError(), still even after error then() block executes.

Comment: if you get error return null and you add null check first part

Comment: I can't understand what u need.

Comment: @Augusto HomePage should be opened if sign up is successful. Problem is HomePage is opened even if the sign up process fails.

Comment: @MehmetAkifBAYSAL , Right , that could be a solution.

Comment: Got the solution, screen navigation should be done inside signUpWithEmail().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You is returning to `signUpWithEmail()` of anyway, you don't throw the error, so it never will enter on

```
.catchError((error) {
      print("THE ERROR : $error");
 })
```

To fix it you must throw the error on your `signUpWithEmail()`. Try something like it.

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> signUpWithEmail() async {
    String email = emailControlller.text;
    String password = passwordControlller.text;

    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailControlller.text,
      password: passwordControlller.text,
    )
        .then((user) {
      // set balance to 0
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .document(user.uid)
          .setData({"cash": 0});
    }).catchError((e) => { 
        print("error : $e")
        throw("Your error") // It return to catch
    });

    return user;
   }
```

Let me know if you can make it.

Comment: May be you are right. I solved it in other way, by moving the screen navigation part inside signUpWithEmail() and there the catchError() part is catching the expected errors.

Comment: This is not a good practice. A good way is separate the services from the screens or widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) widget and wrap the logic in the builder method